# Is there a way to develop new JSR's for Java ME enabled devices?

Tags: java-me, mobile, mobile-phones, sip

I have a MIDP2.0 mobile device with no support for a specific JSR (it's JSR 180 SIP API for J2ME). [Sun's website](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/sip/) says there's a reference implementation but  it seems it's already removed.

The question is, can I develop JSR 180 and deploy it to the device, so applications can use it? Or should it be in the device firmware (obviously I don't have easy access to it)?

Thank you for answers, links, guides, any information I can get (for a noob trying to remember Java ME).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSRs are part of the device's Java ME platform and therefore you (as an application developer) cannot modify them (including adding new classes).

However, there is nothing stopping you from reimplementing some (or all) of the features of a JSR in your own application, working around the problem. However, you would not be able to duplicate the correct package names to make your code 'fully' compliant with the actual JSR.

I have not looked at JSR 180 myself, so I don't know how much extra work this would be, but I have in past done something similar with JSR 172 (XML/Web Services) where I wrote my own basic XML parser and web services wrapper.

Comment: Actually I just want to enable SIP functionality, so being "fuly" compliant is not the aim (probably). But I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: As I said, SIP is not my area, but I wish you luck.

Answer (score 1):

Even without knowing what actual handset you are targetting, it is safe to say that it is very unlikely you will be able to add a new JSR to it.

[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731143/how-to-create-custom-jvm/731523#731523) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950023/j2me-development-and-native-api/950845#950845) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048994/sqlite-and-j2me/1057632#1057632) [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781274/how-to-implement-a-jsr-specification/959811#959811).